# make `git help` produce output in current window, rather than new Explorer window

Tags: git, command

When I write `git help branch`, it opens up a new window in explorer.

What command should I use and where to put so that I get help docs open in git bash not in window explorer browser ?

Comment: What OS do you use? What about using `git branch --help`?

Answer (score 1):

`git help -m` will force the help page to open in "manual" form in the console.

Comment: I failed to make it work for a specific command. Is it possible? If yes, which syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `git <command> -h` which has this specific behaviour

`git <command> --help` --> opens web browser for man page
`git help <command>` --> opens web browser for man page

`git <command> -h` --> outputs man in CLI

Comment: What’s the behaviour difference?

Comment: `--help` opens a browser tab for the web man page, while `-h` outputs the command summary directly in the CLI. But your question makes me wonder... is it config based?

Comment: I didn't find a reference to this behaviour in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help), nor specific config entries in the test repo I used to test it. But it works well.

Comment: @evolutionxbox If I may ask: did you have a chance to test this? `git branch --help` (opens git branch man page in browser) then `git branch -h` (outputs git branch man page in terminal)? I wonder if it's standard behaviour or if something makes them different in my specific context only. Because if the latter is true, I'd love to know what...